# CALayer transform doesn't apply if NSView isn't created yet at the moment

Tags: macos, cocoa, calayer, nsview, appkit

*Environment*: OS X 10.11 SDK, XCode 7.2, Cocoa;

*Context*: Some complex transformation should be applied in the moment of views creation;

When I'm trying to add NSView programmatically transform property is simply ignored if it's placed before `addSubview` call:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
   NSView *view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    CALayer* newLayer = [CALayer layer];

    newLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);

    [newLayer setBackgroundColor:[[NSColor greenColor] CGColor]];

    [view setLayer:newLayer];
    [view setWantsLayer:YES];
    [_window.contentView addSubview:view];
}

- (IBAction)click:(id)sender {
    angle += 0.1f;
    [[_window.contentView subviews] objectAtIndex:2].layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
    CATransform3D t = [[_window.contentView subviews] objectAtIndex:2].layer.transform;
    [[_window.contentView subviews] objectAtIndex:2].layer.edgeAntialiasingMask = !CATransform3DIsIdentity(t);
}
```

[image: screenshot]

If I click on the button, the view would rotate as it should. Also, applying transformation **after** adding the view to the window works too:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSView *view = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    CALayer* newLayer = [CALayer layer];

    [newLayer setBackgroundColor:[[NSColor greenColor] CGColor]];

    [view setLayer:newLayer];
    [view setWantsLayer:YES];

    [_window.contentView addSubview:view];
    view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(angle, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);

}
```

Do I miss some requirements or just misunderstood how CALayer transform works?

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere, or are you attempting to file a bug report by posting on SO?

Comment: @bhaller Added the question. I don't think that's a bug, just a lack of knowledge.

Comment: If OS X layers work the way iOS layers work, this is totally expected behavior.

Comment: @matt, maybe I was unclear. Just created project with the same principe: ``` UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    view.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0.5f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
    [view.layer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]];
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:view];
``` And it works perfectly (transformation has applied even before the view added to UIWindow.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I see what you mean. But a view "has" a layer in a very different sense in Mac OS X. iOS views are born with a layer (they can't exist without one), but not every Mac OS X view has one; you have to ask for it (as you did). It's more of a second-class citizen.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I've come up with is not an attractive one but solve the problem. I just postpone the transformation to the moment of the view initial rendering.

```
@interface DebuggableView: NSView
    @property (nonatomic, assign) CATransform3D transform;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) bool shouldBeTransformed;
@end;

@implementation DebuggableView

- (instancetype) initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if (self)
    {
        self.wantsLayer = YES;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layout
{
    [super layout];
    if (self.shouldBeTransformed) {
        self.layer.transform = self.transform;
        self.shouldBeTransformed = NO;
    }
}

@end
```